# Delphi How to have an exclusive relationship between TDBCheckBoxes

Tags: delphi, checkbox

I have a group of db check boxes with a "none of the above" box at the end. What I want to do is if the "none of the above" is clicked, it clears the rest. And if it is already selected, and any other one is clicked, then clear the "none of the above" box.

```
procedure TformLOC30v15.chkC0900AClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
if chkC0900Z.Checked = True then
begin

    if not(tblMNLOC30.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
        tblMNLOC30.Edit;
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900Z').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.Post;
    tblMNLOC30.Edit;
end;
end;

procedure TformLOC30v15.chkC0900ZClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if chkC0900Z.Checked = True then
begin
    if not(tblMNLOC30.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
        tblMNLOC30.Edit;
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900A').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900B').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900C').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900D').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('c0900Z').AsString := 'True';
    tblmnloc30.Post;
    tblMNLOC30.Edit;
end;
end;
```

This works for the most part, but when the "none of the above" is selected, and any other box is clicked, the box is cleared, but the box that was clicked will not be selected unless clicking it again. Does anybody know why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you posting the data you update? Surely this creates inconsistencies in when data is saved?

Answer (score 0):

ok... I figured it out. Here's the end code if anyone is interested.

```
procedure TformLOC30v15.chkC0900AClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
 (Sender as TDBCheckBox).OnClick := nil;
 chkC0900Z.OnClick := nil;
if chkC0900Z.Checked = True then
begin
    if not(tblMNLOC30.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
        tblMNLOC30.Edit;
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900Z').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName((Sender as TDBCheckBox).DataField).AsString := 'True';
    tblmnloc30.Post;
    tblMNLOC30.Edit;
end;
   (Sender as TDBCheckBox).OnClick := chkC0900AClick;
   chkC0900Z.OnClick := chkC0900ZClick;
end;

procedure TformLOC30v15.chkC0900ZClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
chkC0900A.OnClick :=nil;
chkC0900b.OnClick :=nil;
chkC0900c.OnClick :=nil;
chkC0900d.OnClick :=nil;
chkC0900z.OnClick := nil;
if chkC0900Z.Checked = True then
begin
    if not(tblMNLOC30.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
        tblMNLOC30.Edit;
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900A').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900B').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900C').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('C0900D').AsString := '';
    tblmnloc30.FieldByName('c0900Z').AsString := 'True';
    tblmnloc30.Post;
    tblMNLOC30.Edit;
end;
chkC0900Z.OnClick := chkC0900ZClick;
chkC0900A.OnClick := chkC0900AClick;
chkC0900b.OnClick := chkC0900AClick;
chkC0900c.OnClick := chkC0900AClick;
chkC0900d.OnClick := chkC0900AClick;
end;
```

Comment: It seems to me that if clearing `OnClick` handlers solved your problem, then you have have code elsewhere that's triggering these events in response to data changes? If this is the case, then really all you're doing is slapping on more plasters to patch a leaky design. (See my comment on the question above.)

Comment: Actually what was happening was both of these were calling themselves recursively. There is nothing else that calls the handlers.